# Suppose $X_1, X_2 ...$ are i.i.d random variables with $E|X_i|<\infty$ and $EX_n\rightarrow \mu$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

How does this imply that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}EX_k\rightarrow\mu$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 2):

This follows from a fact from analysis: Suppose that $a_n$ is a convergent sequence with $a_n\rightarrow a$. Let $b_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. Then also $b_n\rightarrow a$.

Try proving this.

Comment: Even more simply:  If the $\{X_i\}$ variables are i.i.d. then $E[X_i]$ is the _same_ for all $i$.